# $\Gamma(K:\mathbb(Q))=G$ and $Fix(G)$ for $K=Q(\alpha), \alpha^4=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^4=2$. I'm trying to work out $\Gamma(K:\mathbb{Q})=G$ and $Fix(G)$.
I've been trying for a while but haven't really got anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: This is **not** a Galois extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not a Galois extension.

Nevertheless, let's assume that $G=\Gamma(K:\mathbb{Q})$ is the set of automorphisms of $K$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}$.

An automorphism of $K$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is determined by the image of $\alpha$ because every element of $K$ is of the form $p(\alpha)$ with $p \in \mathbb Q[X]$.

An automorphism of $K$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ must send $\alpha$ to a root of $X^4=2$ in $K$.
The complex roots of $X^4=2$ are $\pm\alpha$ and $\pm\alpha i$.
Since $K \subseteq \mathbb R$, the only roots of $X^4=2$ in $K$ are $\pm \alpha$.

Therefore, there are exactly two automorphisms of $K$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}$: one that sends $\alpha$ to $\alpha$ (it's the identity) and the other that sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$.

Thus, $G$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: I understand the definition of G, but I don't understand how you are meant to work out the automorphisms of K that fix $\mathbb{Q}$, I think this comes from not entirely understanding the group $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Does K have a basis of $a,\alpha, \alpha ^2,\alpha ^3$ $a \in \mathbb{Q}$? So does that mean the set of automorpisms that fix $\mathbb{Q}$ map any rational to another rational but map $\alpha$ to $\alpha$ , $\alpha  ^2$ or $\alpha  ^3$ etc

Comment: Surely by the definition of Galois Group and Fix, the Fix(G) is just $\mathbb(Q)$

Comment: Isn't $-\alpha$ also a root?  So that means $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ is still a candidate for $G$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, oops! You're right, of course! I've fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AlwaysNeedHelp, the question is not about splitting fields.

Comment: @lhf

Sorry, I don't know why I said splitting fields. What I meant to ask was if alpha was a complex root (i.e i*2^{1/4}), then I guess because the other two real roots are not contained in the field extension Q(\alpha), we essentially have the same case as when alpha is simply taken to be 2^{1/4}. (This is just for my own clarification, thank you).